# How to integrate $\int_0^t \frac{1}{x^{w/2}} e^{-c/x} dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, exponential-function

I've come up with the following integral as part of an equation for a generalized flow model for groundwater flow. Unfortunately it doesn't converge. Does anyone know of a way I can manipulate it in order to make it solvable?

$$ \int_0^t \frac{1}{x^{w/2}}  e^{-c/x} dx$$

$1 \leq w \le 3$ and $c$ is a positive number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We make the transformation:
$y=\frac{c}{ x}$. We have: $dx=-\frac{cdy}{ y^2}$, and we can put the integral in the form:
$$
I=c^{1-\frac{w}{2}}\int_{\frac{c}{t}}^\infty y^{\frac{w}{2}-2}e^{-y}dy=c^{1-\frac{w}{2}}\Gamma\bigg(\frac{w}{2}-1,\frac{c}{t}\bigg)$$
where $\Gamma$ is the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The transformation makes sense easily but could you show me how the solution for the integral is derived? Will the incomplete gamma function be defined when (w/2 - 1) is less than 0?

Comment: I think I see now – by definition
$$ \int_{x}^\infty y^{a-1}e^{-y}dy= \Gamma\bigg(a,x\bigg) $$
The $ c^{3-\frac{w}{2}} $
I’m not sure about though.

Comment: I corrected this

Comment: Do you know what the units would be?

Comment: This question is not clear

Comment: What would the units for $Gamma (a,x) be?

Comment: I am really sorry. I don't udnerstand the question. The $\Gamma$ function produces just pure numbers. I don't understand what do you mean by "units"

Comment: I guess I'm thinking along the lines of the dirac delta function, where the units of delta(x-x') is m^-1 (if x is in metres). In the original integral, the exponential term is unitless but x^(w/2) isn't. So I was thinking the gamma function might also have units because of this?

Comment: If $x$ is in meters then $x^{w/2}$ is in $m^{w/2}$, and $dx$ is also in  meters. Also $c$ and $t$ must be in meters. Thus according to the definition of the integral the result should be in $m^{1-w/2}$. This also comes out from the result , as the coefficient $c^{1-w/2}$ has units of $m^{1-w/2}$ and $\Gamma$ is unitless.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful for my work.